# Contract name could not be found when Mock testing.

Tags: c#, wcf, testing, moq

I am going in circles trying to figure out this error. I am performing a Mock test using moq framework. The test code is

```
[TestFixture]
[ServiceContract]
public class UnitTest1
{

    private ServiceHost host;
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Mock mk = new Mock<ChatInterfaces.IChatService>();
        host = new ServiceHost(mk);
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IChatService), new NetTcpBinding()
            , "net.tcp://localhost:8080/ChatService");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Testing");
```

App.Config file has following bindings

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ChatInterfaces.IChatService">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8080/ChatService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BindingConfiguration" name="ChatServiceEndPoint" contract="ChatInterfaces.IChatService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="BindingConfiguration" transferMode="Buffered"/>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When I run it I get following error.

```
Result Message: System.InvalidOperationException : The contract name     'ChatInterfaces.IChatService' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'Moq.Mock`1[[ChatInterfaces.IChatService, ChatInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.
```

What am I doing wrong here and how to fix it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `mk.Object` to actually get the `IChatService` implementation, rather than the `Mock<T>` object.

```
Mock<ChatInterfaces.IChatService> mk = new Mock<ChatInterfaces.IChatService>();
host = new ServiceHost(mk.Object);
```